# Combine two tables except the rows that exist in first table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have following two tables:

**Table A:**

```
id, name
1, 'John'
```

**Table B:**

```
id, name
1, 'Doe',
2, 'Name 1'
```

I want to select ALL rows from Table A and **ONLY** those rows from Table B where the "id" values does not exist in the Table A.

So from the above data I should get

```
1, 'John'
2, 'Name 1'
```

How can I get that?
I am trying using `EXCEPT` and WHERE `NOT IN` condition as following but I am getting errors.

```
select * from TableA a
union 
select * from TableB b
except (select * from TableB where TableB.id NOT IN TableA.id) 
order by id


select * from TableA a
union 
select * from TableB b
WHERE b.Id  NOT in (select * from TableA where TableA.id = b.id) 
order by id
```

Comment: The official documentation shows you the correct syntax for using those constructs.

Comment: You need a FULL OUTER JOIN - then use ISNULL or COALESCE to get values from the second table when there is no match from the first table.

Answer (score 3):

You're not using the proper syntax. `EXCEPT` expects a data set that matches (much like UNION).
`NOT IN` expects a set with a single column.
Additionally you could also use the `LEFT OUTER JOIN` method.

It's worth pointing out that the `EXCEPT` is applied to the product of the `UNION`.

```
DECLARE @TableA TABLE (ID INT, Name VARCHAR(10));
INSERT INTO @TableA (ID, Name) VALUES (1, 'John');
DECLARE @TableB TABLE (ID INT, Name VARCHAR(10));
INSERT INTO @TableB (ID, Name) VALUES (1, 'Doe'), (2, 'Name 1');

SELECT a.ID, a.Name
  FROM @TableA a
UNION ALL
SELECT b.ID, b.Name
  FROM @TableB b
    LEFT OUTER JOIN @TableA a
      ON b.ID = a.ID
 WHERE a.ID IS NULL

SELECT a.ID, a.Name
  FROM @TableA a
UNION ALL
SELECT b.ID, b.Name
  FROM @TableB b
 WHERE b.ID NOT IN (SELECT ID FROM @TableA)

 SELECT a.ID, a.Name
  FROM @TableA a
UNION ALL
SELECT b.ID, b.Name
  FROM @TableB b
 EXCEPT (SELECT ID, Name FROM @TableA)
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use A `FULL OUTER JOIN`

```
SELECT
COALESCE(A.[id],B.[id]) id, COALESCE(A.[name],B.[name]) name
FROM TableA A FULL OUTER JOIN TableB B ON A.id = b.id
```

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 'John' |
| 2 | 'Name_ 1' |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/4uA3proj)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT id, name FROM TableA UNION SELECT B.id, B.name FROM TableB B LEFT JOIN TableA A ON B.id = A.id WHERE A.id IS NULL;
```